# How to persistently add self-signed cert to update the service reference from within Visual Studio?

Tags: wcf, azure, ssl-certificate, visual-studio-2015, self-signed

I have self-signed cert I'm using in my Azure-WCF-WebRole project. I once could just hit `Update Service Reference` and the local service consumer just updated the references properly.

My `VM` was probably re-created someday and since then I can't do it anymore (with error message `There was an error downloading 'https://....svc/$metadata'.`. Googling around told me to [run `Fiddler`, decrypt HTTPS](http://proq.blogspot.co.il/2012/02/svcutil-and-https.html) and then I'd be able to succeed.

It works, but only when `Fiddler` runs. Once closed, `Update Service Reference` stops working.

I added the certificate to my `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`, but the issue remains.

How can I persistently add the certificate so I need not to run `Fiddler` each time I want to update the service reference in Visual Studio (2015, FWIW)?